# highlight current page nav

Tags: jquery, include, nav

page is: http://rezolve.4pixels.com/banks-and-telcos/demo/index.php#

I want my navigation to show the page I'm on by adding the class "active" to a specific "li", but my navigation is an include. I know how to do that on a single page scrolling site as I'm just detecting when I click a link and adding a class to a parent 'li'.

I'm not sure how I work this when using an include (nav) rather than just a fixed nav (code on the page) where I could just manually add the 'active' class where required on each page.

I know I'd need to start with a 'window.location.href' to get the page I'm arriving at, but then I can't get my head round tying that to a specific menu item to add my active class.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an data attribute to the element which you would like to have an active state.
Make the data attribute equal tot the URL of the page and check with Javascript to add an active class on page load.

I'm not sure if this is the easiest way to do this, but it will work well.

Answer (score 0):

Upon document ready, you can compare the href to the current page url

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentPageUrl = location.href;
  $('li a').each(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('active', this.href === currentPageUrl);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hipady, getting close ;)
I've got that working for nav items with no dropdown, but not sure why it's not working from links inside the dropdowns. They're targeted with the ".nk-nav li a" the same and I thought it would find any "li" up the DOM with 'parents' to attach the active class to.

       $(document).ready(function(){
     "use strict";
        var currentPageUrl = location.href;
        $('.nk-nav li a').each(function(){
        $(this).parents("li").toggleClass('active', this.href === currentPageUrl);
       });
       });